# jquery - When using tablesorter, datepicker stops working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, tablesorter

I need help using datepicker and tablesorter on the same page.  I am able to get this jquery functions to work if one or the other is on the page, however not both.  Below is my code.  Any help is appreciated.

When deleting the javascript for tablesorter, datepicker works.  When adding back the code for tablesort, then datepicker does not work.

```
Code for TableSorter
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(
function() 
{     
$("table")
.tablesorter(
{         
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object         
        headers: {             
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero)
            6: {                 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false
                  sorter: false             
               }
        }  
     });
 });
```

Code for Datepicker:

$(function(){

```
    // Datepicker
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true
    });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Any time html is replaced in DOM, events bound to it are lost ( with exception of deep cloning). That means all the datepicker events are gone.

The plugin API triggers a custom event when sort ends.

```
$('table').on("sortEnd",function() { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true
    });

});
```